# How to make Puppet join specific group and environement?

Tags: puppet

I am wondering is there is a way to make a Puppet agent join a specific Host Group and a specific Environment? This should be done from the Agent without the need to run this from Puppet master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the environment to use with the following command:

```
puppet agent -t --environment <YOUR TEST ENVIRONMENT>
```